# How to do correlation for web_custom_request body

Tags: loadrunner

My web_custom_Request Body:
"Body=AJAXREQUEST=_viewRoot&uniqueToken=1&primaryDependentListId=dataForm%3Awarehouse&dataForm%3Awarehouse=2010&dataForm%3AbussinessUnit=1&dependantId=&RegionID=2010&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3AfieldName=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3AfilterName=FL_venkat&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Aowner=venkat&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3AobjectType=FL_FILTER&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3AfilterObjectType=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield0value1=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield0=FILTER.FILTER_NAME&"
        "dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield0operator=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield1value1=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield1=FILTER.IS_DEFAULT&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield1operator=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield2value1=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield2=FILTER.IS_PRIVATE&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield2operator=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield3value1=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield3=FILTER.OWNER&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield3operator=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield4value1=&"
        "dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield4=FILTER.IS_DELETED&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3Afield4operator=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3AfltrCondition=&dataForm%3AfltrListFltrId%3AfltrCrtSel=&stackId=Stack0&stackId=Stack0&clickedidhdn=101&ItemMaskComp_dependantId=&ItemMaskComp_returnId=&defaultBU=1&dataForm%3AItemLookup_selectOneMenu=-1&dataForm%3AisFind=&findHiddenParam=&dataForm%3AItemLookup_PrimaryAliasText=&dataForm%3AItemLookup_PrimaryAliasTextds=&dataForm%3AItemLookup_PrimaryXREF_Textds=&itemName=&"
        "dataForm%3AItem_LookUP_ItemObjectId=&dataForm%3AownerUserId1=&userSetName=&dataForm%3AtaskHdrIdOut=null&dataForm%3AisHeaderDetail=Header&dataForm%3AidInptPrintRendere=false&taskCriteriaName=&dataForm%3AtaskCreationCriteria1=&dataForm%3AallocInvnDtlId1=&pgBrkSetName=&docIdSetName=&taskIdSetName=&dataForm%3AdocIdValue=&dataForm%3AtaskIdValue1=&dataForm%3AviewTaskValue1=&dataForm%3AviewTaskTemp1=&dataForm%3AmenuIdforDisable="
        "rm_PrintTaskLabel_167271477_menuItem%2CdataForm%3Arm_167271477_menuItemBtn%2Crm_PrintTaskLabel_167271477_rCMItem%2CrmButton_1PrintTaskLabel1_167271477&currentInvnNeedType=&dataForm%3AtranName=TaskListReport&targetLink=&dataForm%3AprimaryKeys=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AradioSelect=quick&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3A_fltrExpColTxt=DONE&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3A_filtrExpColState=collapsed&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield1=TaskID&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield1operator=%3D&"
        "dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield1value1ecId=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield1value1=2748136&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield2=TaskType&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield2operator=%3D&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject2=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield2value1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield3=HeaderStatus&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield3operator=%3D&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject3=&"
        "dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield3value1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield6=Item&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield6operator=DY&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject6=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AitemLookUpId=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield8=CreateDateTime&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield8operator=BT&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject8=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield8value1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield8value2=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield9=WMOrder&"
        "dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield9operator=%3D&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject9=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield9value1ecId=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield9value1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield4=WaveNumber&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield4operator=%3D&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject4=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield4value1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield5=Priority&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield5operator=%3D&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject5="
        "&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield5value1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield20=TaskGenerationReferenceCode&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield20operator=%3D&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject20=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield20value1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield21=TaskGenerationReferenceNumber&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield21operator=%3D&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject21=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield21value1ecId=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield21value1"
        "=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield22=TaskCompletionReferenceCode&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield22operator=%3D&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject22=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield22value1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield23=TaskCompletionReferenceNumber&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield23operator=%3D&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject23=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield23value1ecId=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield23value1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield28="
        "DocumentID&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield28operator=%3D&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AsubObject28=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield28value1ecId=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Afield28value1=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AcurrentAppliedFilterId=-1&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AfilterId_quickFilterGroupButton_mainButtonCategory=-1&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AfilterId_quickFilterGroupButton_mainButtonIndex=-1&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AfilterId_quickFilterGroupButton_changeDefault=false&"
        "dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AfilterId_savedFilterGroupButton_mainButtonCategory=-1&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AfilterId_savedFilterGroupButton_mainButtonIndex=-1&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AfilterId_savedFilterGroupButton_changeDefault=false&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AdummyToGetPrefix=&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3Aowner=venkat&clickedid=101&fotype=WM_TASK_LIST_INQ&tranId=29&customParams%20=tranId%3D29%26fotype%3DWM_TASK_LIST_INQ%26fromLeftNav%3Dtrue%26clickedid%3D101%26stackId%3DStack0&"
        "queryPersistParameter=%26tranId%3D29%26fotype%3DWM_TASK_LIST_INQ%26clickedid%3D101%26stackId%3DStack0&dataForm%3Alview%3AfilterId%3AobjectType=WM_TASK_LIST_INQ&isJSF=true&filterScreenType=ON_SCREEN&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3Apager%3ApageInput=&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3ApagerBoxValue=&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3AisPaginationEvent=&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3ApagerAction=&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable_deleteHidden=&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable_selectedRows=%23%3A%23&"
        "dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable_selectedRows=&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3AisSortButtonClick=taskHdr.taskId&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3AsortDir=asc&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3AcolCount=&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3AtableClicked=&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3AtableResized=false&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3A0%3APK_0=DUMMYROW&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3A0%3AstatCodeVal=&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3A0%3AstatCodeDescVal=&dataForm%3Alview%3AdataTable%3A0%3AtaskHeaderIdValue=&"

Answer (score 0):

Build your own string to go inside of the web_custom_request().   This is a common problem where you may have a variable number of name|value pairs going back from one iteration to the next.   This leverages heavily your foundation (non performance testing tool skills ) in the string manipulation skills in programming language of your tool, in this case LoadRunner and 'C.'

Comment: Thanku james for replaying..script is working fine..I have added the web_reg_ssave_param_ex function..

Answer (score 0):

This request body is URL-encoded. In order to transform it to a more readable form, you may try a DFE ([Data Format Extension](http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/c_web_data_format_extensions.htm)) approach:

1. Enable DFE and [create a DFE chain](http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/t_web_create_chains_of_DFE.htm) with `Url Encoding DFE`.
2. Apply this chain to the request body, refer to [this page](http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/c_DFE_modify_string.htm).

This would decode it to XML form. Then you'd be able to correlate data in the request.

Also this looks like a common POST request so I suspect that you are possibly using `URL-based script` recording level with custom requests. If it is so, you should consider switching to `HTML-based script` and re-generating the script. This would convert this custom request to a higher-level call, e.g., `web_submit_form()`. Check [this](http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/116850_c_recording_levels_overview.htm) and [this](http://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-Practitioners-Forum/Recording-modes-Web-HTTP-HTML-protocol/td-p/6741266) for more information, the last link requires an HPE Passport account.

Comment: Hi Thanku for replying..Script is working fine..i have done the correlation for the body..web_reg_save_param_ex